# How to use a TeX macro with a CSV list to filter an external file

Tags: macros, expansion, shell-escape

The code below produces the results I desire, which is a list of the lines with `XXX={<value>}` with a `<value>` which is not one of the allowed list of values:

[image]

However, this solution requires me to have the same information in two places which is very error prone. So, is there a way I can generated the sequence of the `grep -v` macros based on the contents of `\ListOfAcceptableValues`.

A brute force solution I can think of is to use multiple files for each element in the list of allowed values, but am thinking that there is probably a more elegant way to do this.

### Notes:

- I only need it to work on MacOS, so all the Unix utilities are available.
- Am using `cat` here as it better emulates the actual usage of this macro.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}

%\usepackage{filecontents}% Commented out to prevent overwriting FileA.tex
\begin{filecontents*}{FileA.tex}
    XXX={AA}
some other tex content
    XXX={YY}
    XXX={BB}
and some more tex content
    XXX={ZZ}
    XXX={CC}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\ListOfAcceptableValues}{AA,BB,CC}%

%% How do I rewrite this to make use of \ListOfAcceptableValues
\immediate\write18{%
      cat FileA.tex
    | grep "XXX="
    | grep -v AA
    | grep -v BB
    | grep -v CC
    > FileB.tex
}

\DTLloadrawdb[noheader,keys={Problem}]{MyDB}{FileB.tex}%
\DTLdisplaydb{MyDB}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\def\foo#1,#2{| grep -v #1 \ifx\relax#2\else\expandafter\foo\expandafter#2\fi}
%% How do I rewrite this to make use of \ListOfAcceptableValues
\immediate\write18{%
      cat FileA.tex
    | grep "XXX="
    \expandafter\foo\ListOfAcceptableValues,\relax
    > FileB.tex
}
```

Answer (score 5):

A pure LaTeX (3) solution; the initial spaces are not preserved, though.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{FileA.tex}
    XXX={AA}
some other tex content
    XXX={YY}
    XXX={BB}
and some more tex content
    XXX={ZZ}
    XXX={CC}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \g_grill_acceptable_seq
\seq_new:N \l__grill_temp_seq
\ior_new:N \l_grill_input_stream
\iow_new:N \l_grill_output_stream

\NewDocumentCommand{\SetAcceptableValues}{m}
 {
  \seq_gset_split:Nnn \g_grill_acceptable_seq { , } { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\ExamineFile}{mm}
 {% #1 = input file, #2 = output file
  \grill_examine_file:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \grill_examine_file:nn #1 #2
 {
  \ior_open:Nn \l_grill_input_stream { #1 }
  \iow_open:Nn \l_grill_output_stream { #2 }
  \ior_open:Nn \l_grill_input_stream { #1 }
  \iow_open:Nn \l_grill_output_stream { #2 }
  \ior_map_inline:Nn \l_grill_input_stream
   { \__grill_lookup_line:n { ##1 } }
  \iow_close:N \l_grill_output_stream
  \ior_close:N \l_grill_input_stream
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__grill_lookup_line:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__grill_temp_seq { = } { #1 }
  \int_compare:nT { \seq_count:N \l__grill_temp_seq = 2 }
   {
    \tl_if_eq:nxT { XXX } { \seq_item:Nn \l__grill_temp_seq { 1 } }
     {
      \seq_if_in:NxF \g_grill_acceptable_seq
       { \seq_item:Nn \l__grill_temp_seq { 2 } }
       {
        \iow_now:Nx \l_grill_output_stream { #1 }
       }
     }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_eq:nnT {nx}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\SetAcceptableValues{AA,BB,CC}
\ExamineFile{FileA}{FileB}

\DTLloadrawdb[noheader,keys={Problem}]{MyDB}{FileB.tex}%
\DTLdisplaydb{MyDB}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Another solution that uses regular expressions; I've added `\XXX` as the prefix, like you asked in the comment.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{FileA.tex}
    \XXX={AA}
some other tex content
    \XXX={YY}
    \XXX={BB}
and some more tex content
    \XXX={ZZ}
    \XXX={CC}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool,xparse,l3regex}

\newcommand{\XXX}{XXX} % just to print the database

\ExplSyntaxOn
\regex_new:N \g_grill_prefix_regex

%% Here you set the prefix
%% We specify \XXX, any number of spaces and =
\regex_gset:Nn \g_grill_prefix_regex { \c{XXX} \s*? = }
%%
\regex_new:N \l__grill_acceptable_regex
\seq_new:N \g_grill_acceptable_seq
\seq_new:N \l__grill_temp_seq
\ior_new:N \l_grill_input_stream
\iow_new:N \l_grill_output_stream

\NewDocumentCommand{\SetAcceptableValues}{m}
 {
  \seq_gset_split:Nnn \g_grill_acceptable_seq { , } { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\ExamineFile}{mm}
 {% #1 = input file, #2 = output file
  \grill_examine_file:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \grill_examine_file:nn #1 #2
 {
  \ior_open:Nn \l_grill_input_stream { #1 }
  \iow_open:Nn \l_grill_output_stream { #2 }
  \ior_open:Nn \l_grill_input_stream { #1 }
  \iow_open:Nn \l_grill_output_stream { #2 }
  \regex_set:Nx \l__grill_acceptable_regex
   {
    \exp_not:n{\cB.}
    (\seq_use:Nnnn \g_grill_acceptable_seq { | } { | } { | } )
    \exp_not:n{\cE.}
   }
  \ior_map_inline:Nn \l_grill_input_stream
   { \__grill_lookup_line:n { ##1 } }
  \iow_close:N \l_grill_output_stream
  \ior_close:N \l_grill_input_stream
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__grill_lookup_line:n #1
 {
  %% Check if the prefix is present
  \regex_match:NnT \g_grill_prefix_regex { #1 }
   {
    %% Check whether the value is not among the acceptable ones
    \regex_match:NnF \l__grill_acceptable_regex { #1 }
     { \iow_now:Nn \l_grill_output_stream { #1 } }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_set:Nn { Nx }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\SetAcceptableValues{AA,BB,CC}
\ExamineFile{FileA}{FileB}

\DTLloadrawdb[noheader,keys={Problem}]{MyDB}{FileB.tex}%
\DTLdisplaydb{MyDB}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works for the given MWE, but has issues for instance with `\XXX={YY}`. That was why I was trying to do it in the Unix shell. Not that that was mentioned in the original specification though.

Comment: @PeterGrill The regex solution can take care also of that case.